# observer does not capture place order - magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am working in simple event/observer module, but it does not work. I am trying to log the message in **deubug.log** when click place order button.

I have listed below what I have done

**app/code/Gworks/Sms/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_directpost_placeOrder">
    <observer name="get_place_order" instance="Gworks\Sms\Observer\LogAddMessage"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Gworks/Sms/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Gworks_Sms" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Gworks/Sms/Observer/LogAddMessage.php**

```
<?php
namespace Gworks\Sms\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class LogAddMessage implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;
    public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
    array $data = []
    ) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    //parent::__construct($data);
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $this->_logger->addDebug('getplace oreder event occured successfully!');
    }
}
```

**app/code/Gworks/Sms/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Gworks_Sms',
    __DIR__
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your event `checkout_directpost_placeOrder` is wrong.It is only fire whenever Payment method is `Authorizenet Directpost`

use `sales_order_place_after` **event**.

Comment: thank you it solved @Amit Bera please update how to find right events, its become more useful answer :-)

Comment: it totally  depend on my concept .`directpost` word give me some signel :)

Comment: in which file/line `sales_order_place_after` is dispatched?

Comment: you can see a list of the events in this site https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/ . Thanks Amit

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the events for your case.All events are used for place order after logic.

```
sales_order_place_after

checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```