# order details in observer not working - magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am trying to get order details in observer (**event:** checkout_submit_all_after). I am trying to print the order details in **debug.log**, but nothing printed.

Please refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112622/observer-does-not-capture-place-order-magento-2-0-1) know about my complete module structure. I could change observer class functionality like below for getting order details.

**app/code/Gworks/Sms/Observer/LogAddMessage.php**

```
<?php
namespace Gworks\Sms\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class LogAddMessage implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;
    public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
    array $data = []
    ) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
       // parent::__construct($data);
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $this->_logger->addDebug('getplace oreder event occured successfully!');
    }

    public function getOrder(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
    $this->logger->addDebug($order_id);       
    }
}
```

**debug.log**

`[2016-04-26 10:14:10] main.DEBUG: getplace oreder event occured successfully! {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-04-26 10:14:10] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://magentodev.gworks.mobi/magento2/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category_2","catalog_category_26","catalog_category_30","catalog_category_34","catalog_category"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []`

when define order details in execute method it will throw the below error while place order

[image]

```
[2016-04-26 11:37:42] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Report ID: webapi-571f53065307a; Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 277' in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:194
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(163): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
```

complete module in [Github](https://github.com/gworksmobi/Magento-2)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working finaly

**app/code/Gworks/Sms/Observer/LogAddMessage.php**

```
<?php
    namespace Gworks\Sms\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class LogAddMessage implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $order;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
    array $data = []
    ) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
       // parent::__construct($data);
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
/* @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
        $this->_logger->info($order_id);
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
        $order_information = $order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $this->_logger->info('Order Info', $order_information->getData());
    }

}
```

order details are printed in **system.log**

**note:** thanks to all for give supports :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Use** `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();`

**instead of** $`order = $observer->getOrder();`

Also,you can use `checkout_submit_all_after` event

Comment: still the problem remains, I have updated my question. @Amit Bera

Comment: Can u try with `checkout_submit_all_after`

Comment: yes event: `checkout_submit_all_after`

Comment: let me check?....

Comment: Can  u please share ur source code at github'

Comment: ok I will inform you, I have updated my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38897/discussion-between-bilal-usean-and-amit-bera).

Comment: i busy now..let  u reply later

Answer (score 1):

as per my understanding instead of using getOrder() (method), Use only one method execute()..

you can make as many as functions (methods) you want, but just use in the same class..
hope this will solve the problem

Comment: I had already tried, but when click `place order` it throws error, success page did not come when I do like this

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sales_order_save_after` instead of `checkout_submit_all_after` observer.

and create a **events.xml** file inside etc folder and write below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="save_order" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Observer\AfterPlaceOrderObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

create a `AfterPlaceOrderObserver.php` file inside `Model/Observer/` folder and write the below code

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        /* @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order_data = $order->getData();

file_put_contents('order.txt', print_r("\n" . $order_data,true), FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried but it throw error, I have updated the error details in my question

Comment: @BilalUsean, check your `exception.log` file  the **ReportID:** with error will be print. post that error.

Comment: @BilalUsean And please see my updated answer copy  and paste it it will work. from my side it's working perfect..

Comment: I have tried your solution but no luck still the same problem remain

Comment: @BilalUsean the error throwing clearly the data coming up with array of data but you are storing with string. So use `file_put_contents('order.txt', print_r("\n" . $result,true), FILE_APPEND);` this function it will create the file in your **magento2** root folder. try it definitely work. please let me know if it's not working. see my answer updated.

Comment: @BilalUsean Welcome. If it's working accept my answer, it will useful for some one.